# foreach sort results from database

Tags: php, sorting, phalcon

I have 9 blocks, and I want sort it by last news added.
I have code:

```
$projects = Projects::find(['conditions' => 'active = 1', 'order' => 'id DESC']);
    $itemsps = [];
    foreach($projects as $project) {
        if(!$project->{'link_' . $lang. ''}) continue;
        $itemsp['title_md'] = $project->title_md;
        $itemsp['title_ru'] = $project->title_ru;
        $itemsp['link'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/' . $lang . '/' . $project->{'link_' . $lang. ''};
        $category = Categories::findFirst('alias = ' . "'$project->link_md'" . ' OR alias_ru = ' . "'$project->link_ru'");
        $lastCat = NewsCategories::find('categories_id = ' . $category->id)->getLast();

        if($lastCat === false) continue;

        $lastImage = 'uploads/' . $lastCat['news_id'] . '.jpg';

        $itemsp['image'] = $lastImage;

        $itemsps[] = $itemsp;
    }
```

How I can order by last records of:

```
$lastCat = NewsCategories::find('categories_id = ' . $category->id)->getLast();
```

Results in my array:

`itemsps`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know your DB but i bet you can achive your goal with just one query and some tables joins.
Please take some time to understand [phalcon models](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.3/db-models-relationships)

If you still want to use that format you could use `array_multisort()` to sort the array:

```
    $projects = Projects::find(['conditions' => 'active = 1', 'order' => 'id DESC']);
    $itemsps = [];
    foreach($projects as $project) {
        if(!$project->{'link_' . $lang. ''}) continue;
        $itemsp['title_md'] = $project->title_md;
        $itemsp['title_ru'] = $project->title_ru;
        $itemsp['link'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/' . $lang . '/' . $project->{'link_' . $lang. ''};
        $category = Categories::findFirst('alias = ' . "'$project->link_md'" . ' OR alias_ru = ' . "'$project->link_ru'");
        $lastCat = NewsCategories::find('categories_id = ' . $category->id)->getLast();

        $itemsp['lastCat'] = $lastCat; //ADD THIS

        if($lastCat === false) continue;

        $lastImage = 'uploads/' . $lastCat['news_id'] . '.jpg';

        $itemsp['image'] = $lastImage;

        $itemsps[] = $itemsp;
    }

    //ADD THE CODE BELOW

    $lastCat_array = array();
    foreach ($itemsps as $key => $row)
    {
        $lastCat_array[$key] = $row['lastCat'];
    }
    array_multisort($lastCat_array, SORT_DESC, $itemsps);

    print_r($itemsps);
```